# How to change anchor tag text on click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<div class="panel panel-default ">
            <div class="panel-body">
                This Add-on requires access to your Jive Community.
                <span class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm active" role="button" label="Grant access" >Access Granted </a></span>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                This Add-on requires access to Salesforce.com
                <span class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm active" role="button">Access Granted</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to change  "Access Granted" to "Grant Access" in the above html code.
If somebody could help me out that will be fantastic.
(I am using bootstrap CSS).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <body>
    <a href=""></a>
    <!-- to this <a href="http://www.jquery.com">jQuery.</a> -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
    ></script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(submit) {
$('#check').click(function (e) {
jQuery('a').text('Grant Access').text();
 }); 
});

 <script>
    </body>
```

you can set this with onclick and and onload. trying this

Comment: I want the text 'Grant access' to change to 'Access granted' and vice versa on every click.

Comment: you can replace the jQuery('a') to  jQuery('your anchor id or name wich is unique') and also change $('#check') to $('#id of your anchor tag')

Comment: ody>
    <a href="" id="check" name="e">some link</a>
    <!-- to this <a href="http://www.jquery.com">jQuery.</a> -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
    ></script>
 <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function(submit) 
   {
$('#check').click(function (e) {
jQuery('a').text('Grant Access').text();
 }); 
});

 </script>
    </body>

Comment: The "Grant access" text changes back to "some link"after the onclick event is over.how can we fix that